# (iphone) force scrollViewDidEndDecelerating to be called after programmatically scrolling a view?

Tags: iphone, animation, uiscrollview

I animate the scroll with `scrollRectToVisible:animated:`

But `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating` is not getting called.

Is there a way to force the function to be called?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

`scrollViewDidEndDecelerating` won't be called for `scrollRectToVisible` or `setContentOffset` (i.e, scrolling programmatically). If you notice the declaration of this method in the header file it clearly mentions that it's "called on finger up as we are moving".

Now, to address your issue, `scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation` delegate will be called (for `setContentOffset` and `scrollRectToVisible`), which you can use.

Comment: KKK4SO: scrollViewDidEndDeceleration doesn't get called for scrollRectToVisible scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation doesn't get called for actual finger scrolling, is this normal?

Comment: @Eugene: Yes, pretty much normal. scrollViewDidScroll:delegate responds to both.

Answer (score 5):

As you've found, `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating` isn't always called (if you moved a scroll view with your finger and brought it to a stop it wouldn't get called either).

Since `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating` is a delegate method you can force it to be called like this:

```
[[scrollView delegate] scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:scrollView];
```

Comment: OMFG _thank you_!  I was going back and forth with QA not being able to repro a bug and it turned out I just scroll my screen differently than they do :)

Comment: where do you call this at?

Answer (score 5):

I solved it by calling **scrollViewDidEndDecelerating** from **scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation**

```
-(void) scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    [self scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:scrollView];
}

- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    //your code
}
```

Comment: Does this also work if you have both manual scrolling and programatic scrolling (i.e. using `setContentOffSet`)? I.e. if you have this format, and scroll manually won't `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating` be called twice?

Answer (score 1):

Adding the code below fixed an issue in my case.

```
func scrollViewDidEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, willDecelerate decelerate: Bool) {
    if !decelerate {
        scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(scrollView)
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

1. Use `scrollView.delegate`.
2. For very smooth animation of the view, you should add a delegate function.

```
func scrollViewDidEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, willDecelerate, decelerate: Bool)  { 
    if decelerate == false {
        scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(scrollView)
    }
}
```