# UIScrollView - scrollViewDidEndDecelerating not called on automatic scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I had implemented `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating` in my `UIViewController`. I had set the delegate. When the `UIViewController` was loaded, I was automatically scrolling the `UIScrollView` to some x position. As a result, `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating` was called.
However, I just got a live issue where `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating` is not getting called at this time.

Code :

**viewDidLoad :**

```
self.scrollViewCourse.delegate = self  
self.reloadSession()  


func reloadSession() {
    var visible_frame = scrollViewCourse.frame
    visible_frame.origin.x = visible_frame.size.width * 4
    scrollViewCourse.scrollRectToVisible(visible_frame, animated: true)
}
```

**Note :** Neither is `scrollViewWillBeginDragging` getting called.

Comment: This is by design. Both these methods are not called when you scroll using code.

Comment: @AnthoPak : Earlier they used to.

Comment: Please see this : "scrollViewDidEndDecelerating won't be called for scrollRectToVisible or setContentOffset (i.e, scrolling programmatically)" (https://stackoverflow.com/a/6241776/4894980).
You should use `scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation` instead